# Post editor is 89953px tall. How to fix?

Tags: admin, tinymce, editor

Using a self-hosted install updated to 3.3.1, when I go to the edit post screen, the editor is set to a height of 89953px. When I view source, I see the following lines in the markup for the post editor:

```
<iframe id="content_ifr" src='javascript:""' frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area Press ALT F10 for toolbar. Press ALT 0 for help." style="width: 100%; height: 89953px; display: block; "></iframe>
```

I cannot figure out what is causing the editor's height to be set at 89953px. I have tried disabling all plugins and reverting to the default theme, using the 'Use Google Libraries' plugin and clearing all caches, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, the "size of the post box" setting under Writing Settings had been changed to 5000 lines. Putting it back at a sane number has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Goodness, that's pretty funny! Try clearing your cookies. Specifically, there should be a cookie named "TinyMCE_content_size" which is most likely your culprit.